# "{\"error\":\"Invalid command.\"}" How to fix this error? With JSON in R

Tags: json, r

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)

command = "currencyPair"

url <- paste("https://poloniex.com/public?command=", command, sep = "")

raw.result <- GET(url = url)

# names(raw.result)
# [1] "url"         "status_code" "headers"     "all_headers" "cookies" "content"     "date"        "times"      
# [9] "request"     "handle"     

# head(raw.result$content)
# [1] 7b 22 65 72 72 6f

this.raw.content <- rawToChar(raw.result$content)

# this.raw.content
# [1] "{\"error\":\"Invalid command.\"}"
```

I would like to get the above command into Character form so that I can create a Data.frame. What can I do to fix the error line?

Comment: Perhaps `jsonlite::fromJSON(raw.result$content)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into using the `multiple` arugment. For instance,

```
rawToChar(raw.result$content, multiple = TRUE)
 [1] "{" "\"" "e" "r" "r" "o" "r" "\"" ":" "\"" "I" "n" "v" "a" "l"
[16] "i" "d" " " "c" "o" "m" "m" "a" "n" "" "." "\"" "}"
```